# query specific table columns

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

I have table with specific column names. They have the prefix 'file_'.
For example:

| Column Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| name | somename |
| date | 2000-01-01 |
| size | 15 |
| file_type1 | 1 |
| file_type2 | 34 |
| ..... | .... |
| file_typeN | 12 |

The file types columns 'file_typeN' can be added by another team to table (even may be deleted).
So I want to create sql query to select only values for columns with prefix 'file_'.
The one query for the table my_files_description_table, which can have different number of columns with 'file_' prefix.
Something like:

```
select <only columns with 'file_' prefix> from my_files_description_table;
```

I can query all columns with 'file_' prefix:

`SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_files_description_table' and column_name like 'file_%';`

But I don't know what to do with that.

I need the query that for this table

| Column Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| name | somename |
| date | 2000-01-01 |
| size | 15 |
| file_type1 | 1 |
| file_type2 | 34 |

should return

| Column Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| file_type1 | 1 |
| file_type2 | 34 |

And for this table

| Column Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| name | somename |
| date | 2000-01-01 |
| size | 15 |
| file_type1 | 2 |
| file_type2 | 5 |
| file_type3 | 134 |
| file_type4 | 12 |

should return

| Column Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| file_type1 | 2 |
| file_type2 | 5 |
| file_type3 | 134 |
| file_type4 | 12 |

I use PostgreSQL 9.6.

Comment: Unrelated: postgresql 9.6 will reach eol on November 11, 2021! consider upgrading your system.

Comment: That is not possible.